# Customize template tags in Django to filter featured_posts in a blog

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have taken a hint from this post
[Customising tags in Django to filter posts in Post model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346129/customising-tags-in-django-to-filter-posts-in-post-model)

I have  created the template tag but I am not sure how to use it in my html. I have a home.html where I want to show three featured post. I am looking for something like {% for post in featured_post %} and then show the post detail.

Also, do I necessarily need to create a featured_posts.html as in the above post because I don't want any extra page for the featured post. I just want them to add on my home page in addition to other stuff.

What I am trying to do is I have created a template tag as under

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('featured_posts.html')
def featured_posts(count=3):
    if Post.is_featured:
        featured_posts = Post.published.order_by('-publish')[:count]

    return {'featured_posts': featured_posts}
```

The problem I am facing here is I can't import the Post model from model. My directory structure is somewhat like this:-
I have an app named posts.
Inside that I have models.py and templatetags module and inside the template tag I have blog_tags.py

I couldn't do the relative import.

And then created a new page featured_posts.html as under:-

```
<ul>
    {% for post in featured_posts %}
        <li>{{ post.title }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now, I want to use it in my home.html. How can I use it?

Edit:- As mentioned above I could load the models as under:-

```
from posts.models import Post
```

Comment: That's how inclusion tag is implemented. Just as the given link describes: function, template, then call your function within parent/master template. {% for %} loop is gonna be inside your secondary template.

Comment: I am newbie, I have just edited my question on how I am trying to do it. Can you please guide me how to do it?

Comment: You have the same mistake in tag function as the OP from the link. Take a look at the answer there. ` featured_posts.html` is fine.

Comment: Oh yes... I have corrected that . and I am doing this in my home.html `{% load blog_tags %} {% for post in featured_posts %}{{ post.title }}{% endfor %}` Still I am not getting anything in my home.html. 
One of the possible reason as I have mentioned is I haven't included the model class in the tag. (Read above the problem I am facing in doing it) @IvanStarostin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## home.html

```
{% load blog_tags %} 
{% featured_posts %}
```

Call your tag. That's it.

or

```
{% featured_posts count=15 %}
```

Note, `featured_posts` here is not the post list (which is iterated in `for` loop) from context but function name: `def featured_posts(count=3)`. They have the same name in your code and probably this has confused you a little.